# Android Expansion files with one time download

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

From the android developer guide it is said that we cannot upload the apk files which exceeds 5oMb. For further size we need to use the expansion files. My question is that is there any way to make the users download the complete assets by selecting the install option itself from play store? That is I have an app apk with size 4mb and expansion files of size 70mb making a total of 74mb. So I want an option to make users download this whole files selecting Install option from play store.

I found an app doing the same [Link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamelion.rog.free)

Some one please help me sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the perfect solution for this , but may be you can use proguard to compress the files , and hence it will not get exceeded than the maximum limit.

Comment: Can you please suggest the steps for this. I am having video files which are causing this amount of size.